# How to link the URL in Robo Help using Java?

Tags: java, robohelp

I have an application which has lots of UI screens.Each screen will have 'help' button.
When I press help button ,It should link with corresponding help file(Created hel file by robohelp).
for example:
I have created robo help file..in tat, the file will have the user manual for whole related application with different topic.So when I click help button,It should link to corressponding topic in tat file.how to link the same file but diiferent topics for the corresponding screens.

Plz anyone knws the idea,help me?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that RoboHelp creates many different output formats that may be used as the help system. If you are creating WebHelp, take a look at the link below:

http://wvanweelden.eu/robohelp/context_sensitivity_in_webhelp

If you are creating CHM, the process will be similar.

Cheers... Rick :)

Comment: i am not able to open this link..its failed